# Removing menu item doesn't get removed on edit post

Tags: menus, filters, actions, admin-menu

I have removed some menu links for a basic contributor role, just that when the user access the edit post section they re-appear(`wp-admin/post.php?post=24731&action=edit`). What am I missing? This is my code:

```
if (current_user_can('basic-contributor')) {
    function remove_menus_contrib(){

      remove_menu_page( 'edit-comments.php' );    
      remove_menu_page( 'tools.php' );                   
      remove_menu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=directory' );                 
      remove_menu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=city' );    

    }
    add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_menus_contrib' );
    function profile_redirect() {
        $not_allowed = array(
        'edit.php?post_type=city', 
        'edit.php?post_type=directory',
        'tools.php',
        'edit-comments.php'
        );
        $result = str_replace('/wp-admin/', '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
        if (in_array($result, $not_allowed) !== false) {
            wp_redirect(get_option('siteurl') . '/wp-admin/index.php');
            exit;
        }
    }
    add_action('admin_menu', 'profile_redirect');   // disabling access
}
```

Comment: Try [User Role Editor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/) plugin.

Comment: @Ashok Tried that and created a Basic Contributor that can edit_posts (his own) and read.